# EmbeddingLayer with variable input length is incompatible with LinearLayer?

Tags: neural-networks

[`EmbeddingLayer\[size, n\]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmbeddingLayer.html) trains a representation of a list of integers between 1 and `n` into a real vector of dimension `size`.  However, it is a common practice to represent stop characters as 0; for example [the default setting in Keras's `embedding` treats zeros as padding](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/embedding/).

Mathematica's `EmbeddingLayer` supports an option `"Input"->Varying` that would seem to support this, but it doesn't play well with `LinearLayer`.  Consider the following example (in Mathematica 12.3.1):

```
(*some examples*)
good = {5, 4, 3, 1};
bad = {5, 4, 3, 0};
ugly = {5, 4, 3};


(*suppose you specify the input dimension...only the first example will work*)
em = NetInitialize@NetChain[{EmbeddingLayer[2, 5, "Input" -> 4], LinearLayer[1]}];
FailureQ[em[#]] & /@ {good, bad, ugly}  (* {False, True, True} *)


(*suppose you specify "Input"->"Varying", all examples fail*)
em = NetInitialize@NetChain[{EmbeddingLayer[2, 5, "Input"->"Varying"],LinearLayer[1]}];
FailureQ[em[#]] & /@ {good, bad, ugly} 
(*with error: NetInitialize: Validation failed for second layer of net (LinearLayer): 
input port of layer has dimensions RowWithSeparators[" ","\" \"","n","2"], 
but dynamic dimensions are not currently supported by LinearLayer "*)
```

*Question:  What's the correct way to use `EmbeddingLayer` for varying length input (with or without zero padding)?*

FWIW, MXNet uses zero indexing (as [discussed previously on Mathematica stack exchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195608/bug-in-embeddinglayer)), and the [MXNet mx.nd.Embedding documentation](https://mxnet.apache.org/versions/1.6/api/r/docs/api/mx.nd.Embedding.html) doesn't seem to describe anything like [Keras' mask_zero option](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/embedding/). So this may be a limitation in the underlying MXNet engine, rather than in Mathematica *per se*.

Comment: It seems an input with variable length into `EmbeddingLayer` will cause an output with variable length, which means `LinearLayer` will have to have a variable size weight array which I don't think it is nor should be possible. One possible solution could be setting a maximal input length to `EmbeddingLayer`, padding the variable input with explicit net structure before the `EmbeddingLayer`.